# c++ - escape special characters

Tags: c++, string, escaping

I need to escape all special characters and replace national characters and get "plain text" for a tablename.

```
string getTableName(string name)
```

My string could be **"šárka65_%&."** and I want to get string I can use in my database as a tablename.

Comment: ...what characters are special to your database? Standard SQL? Any variation from or extensions to the standard? Are you using an existing database access library, and if so which one?

Comment: Which is your database, what encoding is your string in, how do you define **plain text**? Can you please provide some more details.

Comment: Unicode was invented 20 years ago to solve this problem.  Your operating system is Unicode, your dbase engine is Unicode, the data in the dbase is probably Unicode.  The only problem is that your program isn't.  Use wstring.

Comment: mysql, mssql, oracle -  I cant focus to one particular database. I expect remove all special characters and replace 'š'->'s', 'č'->'c' and so on.

Comment: @Meloun: removing accents is fiddly but doable with a mapping table.  What do you want to do with punctuation and control characters?

Comment: @Hans: even Unicode-enabled databases do not allow punctuation in object names unless they are treated as delimited identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Which DBMS?

- In standard SQL, a name enclosed in double quotes is a delimited identifier and may contain any characters.
- In MS SQL Server, a name enclosed in square brackets is a delimited identifier.
- In MySQL, a name enclosed in back-ticks is a delimieted identifier.

You could simply choose to enclose the name in the appropriate markers.

*I had a feeling that wasn't what you wanted...*

What codeset is your string in?  It seems to be UTF-8 by the time it gets to my browser.  Do you need to be able to invert the mapping unambiguously?  That is harder.

You can use many schemes to map the information:

- One simple minded one is simply to hex-encode everything, using a marker (X) to protect against leading digits:

  ```
  XC5A1C3A1726B6136355F25262E
  ```
- One slightly less simple minded one is hex-encode anything that is not already an ASCII  alphanumeric or underscore.

  ```
  XC5A1C3A1rka65_25262E
  ```
- Or, as a comment suggests, you can devise a mapping table for accented Latin letters - indeed, a mapping table appropriately initialized will be the fastest approach.  The input is the character in the source string; the output is the desired mapped character or characters.  If you use an 8-bit character set, this is entirely manageable.  If you use full Unicode, it is a lot less manageable (not least, how do you map all the Han syllabary to ASCII?).
- Or ...